# (Group By) & (FOR XML PATH) & JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any other approch rather than saving the result of joining (the Table @VT & TableA ) in one Table variable and then from there make the Grouping

```
select ID , 
  STUFF (( select distinct ' / ' +  TA.Reason
            from @VT
            where ( ID  = VT.ID )
            for xml path(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,2,'' ) as XXX

from @VT as VT
join TableA as TA  on ( TA.ID = VT.ID)
group by ID
```

I get this Error

> Column 'TableA.Reason' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You don't need a `group by` in this query, `distinct` will do the job just fine.

Comment: What is the `JOIN` for if the value appears in both tables? All your data is coming from `TableA`, so why the need for `@VT`?

Comment: there are a duplicated values of ID , that is why I need to group ID

Comment: @VT has the only desired IDs , while TableA has all other unwanted IDs

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the tables in the wrong place.  Does this work?

```
select ID , 
       stuff(( select distinct ' / ' +  TA.Reason
               from TableA TA 
               where vt.ID  = ta.ID 
               for xml path(''), TYPE
              ).value('(./text())  [1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') , 1, 2, ''
            ) as XXX
from @VT vt ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
       STUFF (( SELECT DISTINCT ' / ' +  ta.Reason
                FROM TableA ta
                WHERE vt.ID  = ta.ID 
                FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).VALUE('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'
              ), 1, 2, '' 
             ) AS XXX
FROM @VT vt;
```

Comment: I have to use GROUP BY , because , the dupplicated ID values in @VT have different values in the table REASON , so , I need to group the ID , and put all equivalent values of REASON in one line using ( for xml path )

Comment: Won't that be much more expensive operationally? i.e. slower and more resource intensive? I'd think distinct is better to avoid where possible; is there reason to believe otherwise?